# on click of text in text area

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to make each row in text area clickable,, the cursor can be default or pointer doesn't matter. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZqZr/)

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45">
hello
world
</textarea>​
```

I want to make an ajax call on click of text in each row. I can write all the ajax  functionality, all I am trying to figure out is clicking each row in the text are.
Is it possible with text area or is there any other alternative to this.

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I am using `<c:forEach items="${}" var=""> <c:out value="${} /></c:forEach>` inside the text area. Its not exactly the text with paragraph tag. The text is dynamic based on the input selected before this page

Comment: Why does this need to be a textarea as opposed to a set of other text elements?  Doing this with textarea is possible, but extremely complicated.

Comment: This is the requirement from business people :(, its much easier with the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get the text of the line you clicked on. If that is so, then the following works with your example:

```
$("#mytextArea").on("mouseup", function(eventData) {
    var lineHeight = $(this).css("line-height");
    lineHeight = parseInt(lineHeight.substring(0, lineHeight.length - 2));

    var line = Math.floor(eventData.offsetY / lineHeight);
    alert($(this).val().split("\n")[line]);
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g94FM/) - Get Text from clicked line in textarea

The code will take the position the mouse was clicked in within the textarea `offsetY` and divide it by the applied `line-height`. Using `Math.floor()` it will get the line which was clicked and use it as the index element in the array when splitting the lines by `"\n"`.

In addition to make this work I enforced the line-height to be a set `px` value to allow me to calculate the line clicked.

```
textarea{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}​
```

#### Edit - Scrollbars on textarea

Assuming the textarea has a scrollbar, the scrollbar will "distort" the `offsetY` value and you need to add the current scroll position to it like this:

```
$("#mytextArea").on("mouseup", function(eventData) {
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop()
    var lineHeight = $(this).css("line-height");
    lineHeight = parseInt(lineHeight.substring(0, lineHeight.length - 2));

    var line = Math.floor((eventData.offsetY + scrollPosition) / lineHeight);
    alert($(this).val().split("\n")[line]);
});​
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g94FM/1/) - Get Text from clicked line in textarea with scrollbar

I updated the CSS to a fixed height to get a scrollbar like this:

```
textarea{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 100px;    
}
```

Comment: If there is a scroll bar and there is a list of more than 30 rows then do I have to change the line-height ?

Comment: @user525146: I added an example for when the textarea has a scrollbar. The line-height value is up to yourself, what ever you think looks right but I think it should match the font-size. The code should adapt as it pulls the line-height from the applied css. Feel free to play around with different values and CSS. If you have any issues let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use selectionStart to do this.

Here is an example. Feel free to customize for your use. BUt this should get you started.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" onkeyup="getLineNumber(this, document.getElementById('lineNo'));" onmouseup="this.onkeyup();"></textarea>
<div id="lineNo"></div>

<script>

    function getLineNumber(textarea, indicator) {

        indicator.innerHTML = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This should work even if you have dynamic data based on previous page selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cursor position in the `textarea`, figure out what text that is in, then do your ajax.  That being said it would be easier to just to separate elements (`pre`, `a`, `input`) and have each of their click function fire off the ajax call you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could put each line inside a p tag and use the onclick for that:

```
<p onclick="myFunction()">Hello</p>
<p onclick="myOtherFunction()">World</p>
```