# Is it possible to manipulate individual lines of a textarea with HTML or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to find a way to to click individual lines of a textarea and move them to a different location. I have the movement part down but can't find any info on if it's possible to only do single lines. Thanks for any input.

http://jsbin.com/vinuvopimo/edit?html,js,output

```
<html>
<body>



<textarea id="input"> Click me.</textarea> 
<textarea id="output"> </textarea>

<script>

document.getElementById("input").onclick = function() {myFunction()};



function eraseText() {
        document.getElementById("input").value = "";

    } 

 function myFunction() {

    var InputVar = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var OutputVar = document.getElementById("output");

        OutputVar.value = InputVar;

//  cleanup     
eraseText();    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no need for the anonymous wrapping function. You can use `onclick = myFunction;`

Comment: You want to split the text area contents into an array, manipulate the array then use `join` to put them back together.  This might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895233/how-in-node-to-split-string-by-newline-n

Comment: Are you inserting line breaks (or another delimiter) somewhere? Otherwise it's actually a single line wrapped by the browser. Changing the size of the textarea in the jsbin changes the number of 'lines'.

Comment: I'm feeding an array into this function to split each element with a new line 
.join(',').replace(/,/g, '\n').split();

Comment: Found a similar functionality with Jquery for anyone who is interested. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574588/on-click-of-text-in-text-area

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate individual lines - you have to figure out where exactly user clicked. There is few options:

The simplest - to divide left input into many one line inputs (visually you can manipulate css to give it a look of one component), than you can create the logic to move lines anywhere.

If you want to stay with single textarea, you can get mouse event y coordinate and calculate line number.

http://jsbin.com/xirinocora/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll play around with these ideas.